# Differentiate between hotlinking vs user on site

Tags: php, .htaccess

Is there a way to differentiate between a site that is hotlinking an image vs a user that is actually viewing the image on site?

```
<img src="http://example.com/img.jpg">
```

*VS*

user viewing directly on `http://example.com/img.jpg`

Answer (score 5):

Your server can generally tell the difference between a user looking at an image directly on your domain, and another domain hotlinking your image.

The usual solution to stop hotlinking and allow direct viewing is through [**`.htaccess`**](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/howto/htaccess.html), only let Apache serve image files to your domain, do not serve image files to other domains.

So, a user could still go directly to your image file... since your image is on your domain, but your image could not be used in an image tag on another domain.

So, somewhere in your `.htaccess` you would have something like:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www\.)?yourdomain.com [NC]
RewriteRule \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$ - [NC,F,L]
```

There are [**online tools**](http://www.htaccesstools.com/hotlink-protection/) that will help you create these lines of `.htaccess`.

Of course you don't have to be this restrictive, you can allow hotlinking in general, but restrict only hotlinking from "trouble domains."

Further, instead of stoping hotlinking, you can get Apache to serve an image if your choice to hot linkers, instead of the image they request - `http://www.yourdomain.com/hotlink.jpg` in the case below:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?yourdomain.com/.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule \.(gif|jpg)$ http://www.yourdomain.com/hotlink.jpg [R,L]
```

[**.htaccess**](http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/htaccess.html) [**examples**](http://corz.org/serv/tricks/htaccess.php).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response. We want to allow hotlinking completely. I'm just trying to figure out how I can differentiate between hotlinking and actual user visits via htaccess.

Comment: You should check to see if this enough isn't already being stored in a log. If not you need to set up a log. This would all be Apache stuff, not PHP.

Answer (score 2):

You can check the referrer, but this is not 100% accurate.

The user can spoof the referrer and proxies or user settings can strip/alter it.

Comment: For arguments sake lets say the code on a hotlinked site was <a href="http://example.com/img.jpg"><img src=http://example.com/img.jpg"></a> and then a user clicked on it would have a referer. Anyway to differentiate the two cases in that particular scenario?

Comment: Also to clarify i'm guessing you mean that hotlinking leaves no referrer?

Comment: @imgguy Hotlinking can give a referred that doesn't match your own site.